# Dropdown text issue in ionic - cordova on Android device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I am developing an app using Ionic, Cordova on Visual Studio 2015. It works as expected on Ripple emulator, however, on Android device, the dropdowns are blank (See screenshot 1). After selection, the dropdown shows the text (screenshot 2).

Any idea how to fix this?[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Sharing demo code (not using plunkr as this is a mobile app):

HTML:

```
<ion-view style="" id="page9" title="Setup">
<ion-content class="has-header" delegate-handle="setupCtrl">
    <form style="" class="list">
        <label style="" name="Language" class="item item-select">
            <span class="input-label">Language</span>
            <select class="dropdown"
                    ng-model="lang" 
                    ng-options="LanLst.id as LanLst.name for LanLst in languages"
                    ng-change="languageChange(lang)">
            </select>
        </label>
    </form>
    <a class="button button-positive  button-block" id="setup-button8" ui-sref="tabsController.welcome" ng-disabled="dataSetupDone" >Begin</a>
</ion-content>
```

Javascript:

```
.controller('setupCtrl', ['$scope', 'ServiceFactory', 'sharedProperties', '$filter', '$ionicScrollDelegate', function ($scope, ServiceFactory, sharedProperties, $filter, $ionicScrollDelegate) {
$ionicScrollDelegate.resize();

$scope.languageChange = function (lang) {

    sharedProperties.setLanguage(lang);

    $scope.dataSetupDone = true;
    $scope.offline.checked = false;
};
```

}])

Data:

```
Languages: 
[
{ "id": 1, "language": "English"},
{ "id": 2, "language": "Spanish"}
]
```

lang will be id : 1 or 2.

allData will have the actual data.

```
for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; i++)
{
  $scope.languages.push({ "id": allData[i].id, "name": allData[i].language });
  $scope.languagesWithText.push({ "id": allData[i].id, "name": allData[i].languageText });

}
```

Comment: I suggest using GennyMotion- https://www.genymotion.com/. Had a similar problem with our app.

Comment: GenyMotion seems to be an emulator. I am running on actual device.

Comment: Could you post a basic demo or codes that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Elvis: I have added code, not sure how to arrange for demo as this is a mobile app. Further, this is working fine on Ripple emulator (on desktop simulation), the only issue is when we debug / run the app in actual mobile device.

Comment: I tried several css hack but that does not work. I tried changing font color (assuming it is getting white), back ground color of option item, z-index to 100. But none of them worked.

Comment: I noticed, you have a languages array in the scope and bind your current select to $scope.lang. Can you post a sample data of languages and lang?

Comment: I have added data information.

Comment: You use LanLst.name for LanLst in languages by code side but by data side there is no name property, only language.

Comment: @ElvisXia Nice catch. However, this is my mistake that I didn't posted correct code. I have updated the same. Sorry for that. See the "L" is small caps. Further, the code works as expected in Ripple (Chrome) emulator, but not on the actual device - this thing is much bothering. :(

Comment: @TechTurtle I can't reproduce the problem by my side. Could you post a basic demo project that can reproduce this problem? And maybe try with other android devices.

Comment: @ElvisXia Sure. Is it possible to give me a screenshot?

Comment: Which android version you are trying?

Comment: My Android device's android version is 4.4.4.

Comment: I might know what the problem is. Did you define your ng-controller in your html?

Comment: No, it is in different javascript file. route.js.

Comment: And the controller's name is "setupCtrl"? If yes, then everything's ok. Need a demo to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Yes, it has the name as setupCtrl. I will see what I can do to have a demo, suggest me if you already know.

Comment: Are you testing in a Huawei device? I have exactly the same problem, and it works in every device (including iOS), showing native select, excepting this. Link for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272728/select-dropdown-ionic-dont-show-text

Comment: No, I am testing on Asus tab.