# Select dropdown Ionic don't show text

Tags: cordova, dom, ionic-framework, huawei-mobile-services

I am developing an application in Ionic 1.7.

I have a select menu and I am facing a problem with it.

For simplification, my code is like the documentation

```
  <label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
      Lightsaber
    </div>
    <select>
      <option>Blue</option>
      <option selected>Green</option>
      <option>Red</option>
    </select>
  </label>
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#select

It works well with most devices, in iOS and Android. It shows the native select menu, and everything is OK.

But I have a problem with one device, a Huawei MediaPad M2. Its my corporate tablet and this app have to work here.

The problem is, that with any code that involves select menus, the text of the options don't show. The number of the elements are correct, and I think that the labels are OK too, because if I increase the size of the labels, the box grows too.

Screenshot for reference

[image]

If I open the samples in the default browser, It works, the boxes are the same, but the labels show with black text, which don't happens in the ionic app.

I tried to remove all the CSS of ionic, add all CSS that may work, update the webview app of android, update the tablet, and nothing worked.

I tried to create a new sample app with only a select menu, and this happens too.

Any ideas, or workarounds, about how can I fix this, or force to open the native select menu?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it through `chrome://inspect/#devices` (or any other debugging tool - this is just my favourite) when you have your device connected to your pc? If it gives any error messages there. Or you could even inspect the element and see if you can spot something that's wrong.

Comment: Sure, I have been inspecting, and editing all the CSS on the fly, but I didn't do any progress

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening but you could try using Xwalk that might solve your problem. Does the problem show when using the ionic view app as well? Did you try on any other Huawei devices? By the way Ionic is only up to version 1.3.1 I think the version you listed is the CLI version.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'm having the same.

Comment: No, I did a workarround with a custom select, and I have changed my device, and I dont have a Huawei anymore. Try @Dylan answer, and if works, I approve it

Comment: I see. I haven't tried @Dylan's answer because I need to use Phonegap Build to deploy my apps so I can't edit the AndroidManifest.xml. I'll search more about it and if there's no automatic way to deal with it, I'll try a custom select as you did. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I got the correct answer from here:
[Apache Cordova Android 5.0 Select Box Option color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025345/apache-cordova-android-5-0-select-box-option-color-resolved)

Locate AndroidManifest.xml in platforms/android and look for this block:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

The key setting is: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"

When I had the same problem as you, this was set to: "android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar". Setting it to "Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" gave me black text on white in my select dropdowns.

Comment: someone should mark this as the correct answer. Thanks @Dylan

Answer (score 0):

The workaround it to use Select-box plugin. I have the same problem, and meanwhile I get the solution, I am using this plugin.

https://github.com/domiSchenk/ionic-Select-Control

Hope this helps.